# OpenVPN client connects, but no internet access

Tags: linux, openvpn

When i'm trying to connect OpenVPN client from Windows 10, it works fine.

But when i'm trying to connect OpenVPN from ubuntu VDS. It's succesfully connects, but no internet access on ubuntu VDS.

Here is my OpenVPN client config:

```
client
proto udp
explicit-exit-notify
remote 49.12.32.222 1194
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name server_p1Jgr1XxHC3GbYQl name
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
cipher AES-128-GCM
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
setenv opt block-outside-dns # Prevent Windows 10 DNS leak
verb 3
```

Update:
`ip route show` from client (ubuntu server that has no internet access) while connected

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun1
default via 185.151.125.1 dev eth0 onlink
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun1 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.4
49.12.32.222 via 185.151.125.1 dev eth0
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun1
185.151.125.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 185.151.125.67
192.168.6.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.6.1
```

Still need your help.

Comment: What is the output of `ping 142.250.179.142` and `ping google.com`?

Comment: There is no ping.
25 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 24558ms
But it works from Windows 10
I know the issue is that ubuntu is a dedicated server. But my knowledge in setup server networks and linux - is to low.

Comment: Check `ip route show`.

Comment: I've added `ip route show` in main question.

Comment: For `ping` output as @check wrote. Does it fail with both IP and DNS name?

Comment: Do you have more than one VPN active? `ip route show` shows two routes to 10.8.0.0/24 using different devices (tun0, tun1).

Comment: @MathiasWeidner no, i have only 1 active vpn. When i turning off Openvpn routes with tun0 tun1 disappeared from route list.

Comment: @JiriB yes, ping fail with both IP and DNS name